# Fourier transformation with two signals

Tags: fourier-transform

So I have two signals
$$m(t) = 336\cdot\rm{sinc}(24t)$$
$$x(t) = m(t)\cos(400\pi t)$$
How do I calculate fourier transformation for $x(t)$?
I already calculated:
$$M(f) = 14\cdot\rm{rect}(\frac{f}{24})$$
and fourier transformation for $\cos(400 \pi t)$, lets just call this $y(t)$
$$Y(f) = \frac{1}{2}(\delta(f - 200) + \delta(f + 200))$$
$$X(f) = 14\rm{rect}(\frac{f}{24}) \cdot \frac{1}{2}(\delta(f - 200) + \delta(f + 200))$$
which is wrong answer. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look up the convolution theorem for the Fourier Transform

$$\begin{align*}X(f)&=\mathscr{F}\left\{x(t)\right\}\\
\\
&= \mathscr{F}\left\{m(t)\cdot y(t)\right\}\\
\\
&=\mathscr{F}\left\{m(t)\right\}*\mathscr{F}\left\{ y(t)\right\}\\
\\
X(f) &= M(f) * Y(f)\\
\end{align*}$$

Where '$\cdot$' denotes multiplication and '$*$' denotes convolution.  Your answer just appears to have multiplication, given your notation.